# How can I set up some timeout in TeraCopy so that it skip files on which it gets stuck?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, timeout, teracopy

TeraCopy sometimes gets stuck on some problematic files, as shown below. How can I set up some timeout in TeraCopy so that it skipped the problematic files and other file transfers are made?

[image]

I use TeraCopy with Windows 7.

Comment: Are you saying that it requires you to click Skip manually on every failure? Have you checked to see if it has a timeout or skip failed transfer setting already? Other posts online strongly suggest it does.

Comment: @music2myear thanks, the skip button didn't even work on it, but yes basically I don't want to have to click on anything.